# Entering quadratic programming problem in algebraic mode in IBM Cplex using Python API

Tags: python, cplex, quadratic-programming

I would like to enter a complicated objective function in IBM's Cplex using Python API. The easiest way to do this it to enter it in Algebraic Mode. There is some instruction on page 191 of [this document](https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271_pdfs/usrcplex.pdf) on how to enter objective function in Algebraic mode but none for how do so using the Python API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The document says:

> This view is supported by the LP format, when you enter a quadratic
>   objective function in the Interactive Optimizer, and by Concert
>   Technology.

It's directly not available in the CPLEX Python API (an index based API similar to the underlying C Callable Library). However, you can [read](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html#read) an LP file with the Python API, so that is one way to do it.

Another option is to consider using [DOcplex](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) (a modeling language that can utilize a local CPLEX Python API installation or solve on the cloud via the docplexcloud service). See the [Beyond Linear Programming Tutorial](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/tutorials/Beyond_Linear_Programming.ipynb) Notebook for an example of using a quadratic objective with DOcplex.